# Select2 autocomplete not work for dynamic added select element

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-select2

I have the following ajax query which get HTML. This html has a select element having an Id ddlPage.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Settings/GetEfinanceInterfaceSettingLookups",
    //data: arr,
    success: function (data) {
        $("#eFinanceInterfaceModelForm").append(data);
        AfterLookUpLoad();
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert(error);
        //jError('An error has occurred while saving the new part source: ' + jsonValue, { TimeShown: 3000 });
    }
});

   function AfterLookUpLoad() {

        $("#ddlPage").select2({
            placeholder: "Select Type(Screen)",
            allowClear: true

        });
}
```

But its autocomplete not works because when i open the select list i am not able to focus on the text box to type

[image: Not able to focus on text box]

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the HTML structure. Perhaps there's another invisible element overlapping the input box that prevents you from selecting it?

Comment: It works for me when we have select element at the time of DOM creation but not when we add this dynamically at document.ready